# Tax Amount is not updating in sales order when creating programmatically

Tags: acumatica

Tax Amount field is not holding the value when we try to create the sales order programmatically. I'm using the manual tax. From screen it is working fine but while trying to create from code the value is not taking, even I'm trying to provide the values to the field after the order creation it is reverting to 0.

Here the code that i'm using to update the Tax Amount.

```
orderTax.CuryTaxAmt = tax;
sOOrderEntry.Taxes.Cache.Update(orderTax);
sOOrderEntry.Document.SetValueExt<SOOrder.curyTaxTotal>(sOOrderEntry.Document.Current, tax);
orderTotal = sOOrderEntry.Document.Current.OrderTotal + orderTax.CuryTaxAmt;
sOOrderEntry.Document.SetValueExt<SOOrder.curyOrderTotal>(sOOrderEntry.Document.Current, orderTotal);
sOOrderEntry.Document.Cache.Update(sOOrderEntry.Document.Current);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating tax amount in the sales order field is not a good idea. 
CuryTaxTotal field in sales order is calculated field. It is calculated from SOTaxTran lines. 
So, in order to update tax amount in sales order you actually need to insert SOTaxTran lines into Taxes view of the SOOrderEntry graph.

Something like that:

```
//indicate that taxes are inserted in manual mode
TaxAttribute.SetTaxCalc<SOLine.taxCategoryID>(graph.Transactions.Cache, null, TaxCalc.ManualCalc); 
// insert SOTaxTran
SOTaxTran newTaxTran= new SOTaxTran();
newTaxTran.TaxRate = 0.1; //put your actual values here
newTaxTran.CuryTaxableAmt =  100; //put your actual values here
newTaxTran.CuryTaxAmt =  10; //put your actual values here
var taxTran = graph.Taxes.Insert(newTaxTran);
```

Comment: It is a known issue, there really should be a method to force refresh the formula totals IMO.